# lychee photo gallery docker file can't be deploy in the railways.app

Tags: docker, deployment, dockerfile

Hi I have a problem at deploying an image with docker (Lychee photo gallery) on railway.app

I have this Docker file

**Dockerfile.origin** :

```
# Base image
FROM php:7.4-apache

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd mysqli zip exif

# Enable Apache Rewrite module
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Download and install Lychee
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/*
RUN curl -L https://github.com/LycheeOrg/Lychee/archive/master.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1 -C /var/www/html

# Set permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html

# Set ServerName directive
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache service
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

I made to the part that it can be build with the env variable, but when clicking the URL (test-production-0466.up.railway.app) I should expect the lychee app website from the docker image

[image]

[image]

It shows this

[image]

the deploy logs says this

[Wed May 31 16:58:52.820444 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/7.4.33 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed May 31 16:58:52.820525 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'

[image]

What can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just have to add an environment variable railway.app which is **PORT=80**